# What is the best way to run background service in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, background-service

I am trying to run a background service in a little complex way using flutter. These are my goals.

1. Service gets awake every 1 minute.
2. It then makes an api call after the service awakes.
3. I need to also record in the background for a few seconds after the service awakes.
4. Update the UI in the background.

I tried lots of possibilities with the [Work Manager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) and [Flutter Background Service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service/install) package but I got lots of limitations especially on the iOS side of things.

So, I would like to ask, is what I am trying to achieve possible with flutter packages or do I need to write native code on it?

Comment: What you are trying to do is essentially impossible on ios. Native code won't help.

Comment: The closest thing is using https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch, but it has limitations that you can read on its readme. It's better than nothing on iOS

Comment: Also, this is the wrong approach for a mobile app on any platform. Mobile devices are typically battery and network constrained.  You haven't really explained what you are trying to achieve, but it may be better to use push notifications from a server or have your app calll the api when it returns to the foreground

Comment: Try this package [https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service). Worked for me.